# My check digit is always returning 0 no matter what the input is

Tags: java

I have to have a check digit return for a 10 digit isbn number, and it should return either 0,X,or the remainder after I mod the 9 digits by 11. My program is always returning a 0 and I cannot figure out why. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BookNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// Calculate the check digit number for an ISBN
```

// Have user enter the nine digit number to check as an integer
   // Convert the integer to a string to be operated on

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Please enter a nine digit.                    number to check ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    String usernumber = "";
    usernumber = Integer.toString(number);

// Access each character in the string and create a.      numeric value for
// Them as a variable

    int d1 =     Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(0));
    int d2 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(1));
    int d3 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(2));
    int d4 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(3));
    int d5 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(4));
    int d6 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(5));
    int d7 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(6));
    int d8 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(7));
    int d9 = Character.getNumericValue(usernumber.charAt(8));

// Initialize a variable for your check digit
    int CDvalue = 0;

// Perform the instructed calculation (d1*1 + d2*2 + d3*3 + … + d9*9) % 11 == C

 boolean isbnvalue = (d1*1 + d2*2 + d3*3 + d4*4 + d5*5 + d6*6 + d7*7 + d8*8 + d9*9) % 11 == CDvalue;
          if( CDvalue == 0 ){
        int CD = 0;
        System.out.println( "Your check digit is " + CD);
    } else if ( CDvalue == 10){
        System.out.println( "Your check digit is X" );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Your check digit is " + CDvalue);
        }

     }

 }
```

Comment: You never assign a value to CDvalue other than the zero when you declare it.

Comment: Yeah... I expected this to be a weird precedence issue (i.e. that somehow it was parsing it as (big calc) % (11 == 0) which shouldn't be possible in Java unlike C) and then realized that

Comment: Can I suggest you learn how to use arrays and/or loops, it would make this code much easier.

Answer (score 2):

The main part of your code (and I debated when I cleaned up formatting ripping out the rest is):

```
int CDValue = 0;

boolean isbnvalue = (d1*1 + d2*2 + d3*3 + d4*4 + d5*5 + d6*6 + d7*7 + d8*8 + d9*9) % 11 == CDvalue;
if( CDvalue == 0 ){
        int CD = 0;
        System.out.println( "Your check digit is " + CD);
    } else if ( CDvalue == 10){
        System.out.println( "Your check digit is X" );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "Your check digit is " + CDvalue);
        }

     }
```

You never actually use isbnvalue in your code, nor do you change CDValue, so CDvalue is always zero.

Comment: Shouldn't CDvalue change when the calculation is ran ?

Comment: As written: no.  Should it?  Yes, you probably should do something like CDValue = (d1 + d2*2 + d3*3...) % 11;

Comment: Thank you Foon, I realized what was wrong it was staring me in the face ...simple mistake.